# Sqlalchemy Core, insert statement returning * (all columns)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy core (query builder) to do an insert using a table definition. For example:

```
table.insert().values(a,b,c)
```

and I can make it return specific columns:

```
table.insert().values(a,b,c).returning(table.c.id, table.c.name)
```

but I am using postgres which has a `RETURNING *` syntax, which returns all the columns in the row. Is there a way to do that with sqlalchemy core?

Comment: Does `.returning(literal_column('*'))` work?

Comment: @jordanm yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
query = table.insert().values(a,b,c).returning(literal_column('*'))
```

And you can access it like

```
for col in execute(query, stmt):
   print(col)
```

Comment: Hi, this helps me to solve my problem. I would like to contribute one more this. We can get the data like ```dict(res.fetchone())``` instead of for if we want in dict.

Answer (score 13):

To get all table columns, one can also do the following query:

```
table.insert().values(a,b,c).returning(table)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can expand table columns:

```
table.insert().returning(*table.c).values(a,b,c)
```